# Priority Queue with Comparator not working as expected

Tags: java, priority-queue

Priority queue not working as per the order of comparator.

[See code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p773.jpg)

Output:
    [ Tim , 5 ],[ Joe , 12 ],[ Alice , 7 ]

Expected:
    [ Tim , 5 ],[ Alice , 7 ],[ Joe , 12 ]

Can anyone help me why the comparator is not giving expected output.

Comment: The iterator of `PriorityQueue` "does not return the elements in any particular order"

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The Iterator provided in method `PriorityQueue.iterator()` is not
>   guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any
>   particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using
>   `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`

Answer (score 0):

PriorityQueue is a queue, it does not sort the values on the fly. You need to use PriorityQueue.poll method to get the object in order.

```
static class Student {
    String name;
    int roll;

    public Student(String name, int roll) {
        this.name = name;
        this.roll = roll;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "["+ name +","+roll+"]";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }

    public void setRoll(int roll) {
        this.roll = roll;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Comparator<Student> byRoll = Comparator.comparing(Student::getRoll);

    PriorityQueue<Student> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(byRoll);

    pq.add(new Student("Tim", 5));
    pq.add(new Student("Joe", 12));
    pq.add(new Student("Alice", 7));

    while(!pq.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println( pq.poll().toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine, no need to change Comparator or Array.sort or add getter/setters etc. 
Just change your printing statement as below:

```
while(!pq.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(pq.poll().toString());
    }
```

Hope this helps.